# Deploying to Heroku crash: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

I get this error after deploying my springboot application in Heroku:

```
2019-12-12T19:09:35.340701+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-12-12T19:09:35.088497+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2019-12-12T19:09:35.088497+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-12-12T19:09:35.319755+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2019-12-12T19:16:46.351647+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-12-12T19:16:50.604492+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -Dserver.port=35960 $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/*.jar`
```

So I tried to make a Procfile on the root folder of my project and this is the content:

Procfile:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar build/libs/*.jar
```

I also added this line to my application.properties file.

application.properties:

```
server.port=${PORT:5000}
```

However, it's still not working.
The error above is still happening. How do I fix this? What else am I missing?

I'm using gradle, java11 and spring boot.

Comment: can you try adding `server.address=0.0.0.0` to your application.properties too? It looks like you have `port` set correctly

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately. :(